# set variable in forfiles in for cycle

Tags: cmd

```
@Echo On
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO (
    forfiles /M "%%f" /C "cmd /V:ON /c set fn=@ftime"
    echo %%fn%%
)
pause
```

I want to get `@ftime` in `FOR` loop, but this isn't working. Maybe there is another way to get modify time of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method, you are setting a variable `fn` within the `cmd` instance that is opened by `forfiles`, but this variable is no longer available in the `cmd` instance that runs your script.

---

You can use the `~t` modifier of the `for` variable (so `%%~tf` in your code) to get the modification date and time, then split off the time portion by substring expansion (see `set /?`), if the featured resolution of minutes is sufficient (the `"%%~nxF"` portion just precedes the returned time with the current file name):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("*.jpg") do (
    set "FTIME=%%~tF"
    rem The following line depends on region settings:
    echo "%%~nxF": !FTIME:~11!
)
endlocal
pause
```

Alternatively, you can use a `for /F` loop to split off the time part from the date:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("*.jpg") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%I in ("%%~tF") do (
        echo "%%~nxF": %%J
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

---

If you require a resolution of seconds as supported by `forfiles`, you need to echo the `@ftime` value within `forfiles` and capture that by a `for /F` loop, which iterates once only per each file (time) (`@file` returns the current file name, which is then held by `"%%~K"`):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%F in ("*.jpg") do (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%K in ('
        forfiles /M "%%~F" /C "cmd /C echo @file^|@ftime"
    ') do (
        echo "%%~K": %%L
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

---

Depending on your application, you might not need a separate `for` loop to walk through `*.jpg` files, because `forfiles` could do that on its own:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=|" %%K in ('
    forfiles /M "*.jpg" /C "cmd /C echo @file^|@ftime"
') do (
    echo "%%~K": %%L
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: How can I use filename in this cycle?

Comment: If you're talking about the `for` loop, you can use `~nx` instead of `~t` to get the file name + ext. -- type `for /?` in a command prompt window and check out all the possibilities at the end of the help text; if you mean the `forfiles` loop, you need to state `@file` instead of `@ftime` -- type `forfiles /?` in command command prompt to get a full list of all the available `@`-variables...

Comment: I dont get it. How can i echo filename after `echo %%L`?. I need seconds

Comment: Okay, I extended all the code snippets in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34485131/3) so they return the file name plus the related file time now; I hope everything is clear now...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set variables in your batch file from a `forfiles` call because that one will always spawn a new shell. `forfiles` is a program, not a built-in command.

However, you can get the modification time with `%%tf` in your loop, without `forfiles`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO (
    set "fn=%%~tf"
    echo !fn!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly FORFILES, just write output to tempfile:

```
...
set file=temp.txt
...
FORFILES /M "%%f" /C "cmd /c echo @ftime >> %file%"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a In ("%file%") Do (Set fn=%%a | echo %fn%)
DEL %file% /q
```