# ForFiles to batch move & rename file(s) with timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a bunch of *.mp4 & *.jpg files created on an hourly/daily basis, which use the file structure below:

```
-- before:
c:\video\2017-10-15\21hour\jpg\12.13.15[M][0@0][0].jpg
c:\video\2017-10-15\21hour\mp4\12.13.01-12.14.32[M][0@0][0].mp4
c:\video\2017-10-18\16hour\jpg\21.42.31[M][0@0][0].jpg
c:\video\2017-10-18\16hour\mp4\21.42.31-21.45.38[M][0@0][0].mp4
```

I want all the *.jpg & *.mp4 files to get moved to c:\video\ & also completely ditch the old name for 'date_time' + extension, similar to below:

```
-- after:
c:\video\2017-10-15_12.13.15.jpg
c:\video\2017-10-15_12.13.01-12.14.32.mp4
c:\video\2017-10-18_21.42.31.jpg
c:\video\2017-10-18_21.42.31-21.45.38.mp4
```

I discovered ForFiles, and was able to use the /s to recursively search all subfolders & move the *.mp4 & *.jpg to a single location:

```
forfiles /p c:\video\ /s /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c move @PATH c:\video\"
forfiles /p c:\video\ /s /m *.jpg /c "cmd /c move @PATH c:\video\"
```

Now for the renaming, at this point I can almost taste victory as this gives me the desired filename output:

```
forfiles /p c:\video\ /s /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c echo @FDATE_@FTIME.mp4"
forfiles /p c:\video\ /s /m *.jpg /c "cmd /c echo @FDATE_@FTIME.jpg"
```

But when I replace echo with either ren/rename/move, I get errors:
The system cannot find the path specified.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

But the error only happens when I'm using @FDATE and/or @FTIME.  These variables all work fine:  @FNAME, @ISDIR, @FSIZE

```
forfiles /p c:\video\ /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c ren @FILE @ISDIR.@EXT"
forfiles /p c:\video\ /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c rename @FILE @FSIZE.@EXT"
forfiles /p c:\video\ /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c move @FILE @EXT.@EXT"
```

Once I get the renaming part to work, I will combine both the move & rename into one command...  But I can't figure out why @FDATE & @FTIME won't take, is there something wrong with my syntax, or is this just something ForFiles doesn't allow?

Comment: `Move` accepts a new file name for the destination, so I would suggest that you perform both tasks with the same routine. You could perform the rename first, but do not move all of your files before the rename. If you have already done so then both `-- before:` and `-- after:` have changed and your question requires updating accordingly.

Comment: Definitely don't need to use FORFILES.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem explained

Firstly, replacing `echo` with just `move` or `ren` alone will not work because it will only detect one argument being passed to it. This could explain the syntax error.

> #### Syntax of `ren` from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren#syntax)
>
> ```
> ren [<Drive>:][<Path>]<FileName1> <FileName2>
>
> rename [<Drive>:][<Path>]<FileName1> <FileName2>
> ```
>
> #### Syntax of `move` from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move)
>
> ```
> move [{/y | /-y}] [<Source>] [<Target>]
> ```

Secondly, the variables `@FDATE` and `@FTIME` are locale-dependent. Their format will depend on your device's regional formatting, e.g. `@FDATE`'s format could contain `/` and `@FTIME`'s format contains `:`. These are reserved characters and could result in an error if misused. This could explain the path error.

---

### A solution using `forfiles`

If you want to do this with `forfiles` you will have to use the `for` command, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485131/8819027). You can change the date format by extracting substrings like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10945887/8819027). You can change the time format by replacing the colon `:` with a dot `.`, explained [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

You could use `/m` once for .jpg and again for .mp4, but you could also try it like [this `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11719838/8819027). This means you would have to nest the `for` in the example in another `for` loop.

According to the `move /?`, if you move just one file you can rename it as well.

#### Example:

```batch
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (.jpg, .mp4) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=|" %%A in (
        'forfiles /p "C:\video" /s /m "*%%F" /c "cmd /c echo @PATH^|@EXT^|@FDATE^|@FTIME"'
        ) do (
        set filepath=%%~A
        set extension=%%~B
        set datestamp=%%~C
        set timestamp=%%~D
        set parseddate=!datestamp:~6,4!-!datestamp:~3,2!-!datestamp:~0,2!
        move "!filepath!" "C:\video\!parseddate!_!timestamp::=.!.!extension!"
    )
)

endlocal
```

If the file count is large, it will take a little while for batch to finish. `forfiles` has to read the files first and the `for` loop has to also go through that file list. Also, `forfiles` is locale-dependent. If the regional date format of your device is `2020/02/10` then the indices of the substring in my example are not correct.

---

### A solution using PowerShell

.NET Framework's [`LastWriteTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime?view=netframework-4.8) property is locale-independent, as in it does not dependent on your device's regional formatting. There is also a [`LastWriteTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetimeutc?view=netframework-4.8) property if you prefer to use UTC. You will still have to use a `for` loop inside a batch file though.

PowerShell's [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) returns all children of the parent folder specified by the `-Path` parameter and with the `-Recurse` parameter you can do so recursively. If you want the result to include just .jpg and .mp4 files you should use `-Include *.jpg, *.mp4`. Normally when using `-Include` you would need to append `\*` to the path, but since `-Recurse` is used it's not necessary.

With [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty?view=powershell-7) and the `-Name` parameter you can list the `Fullname`, `LastWriteTime` and `Extension` properties. To make it more readable for the `for` loop they have to be called like `$var.Property` and concatenated. [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) must be used to convert `LastWriteTime` to string and change its format.

#### Example:

```batch
for /f "tokens=1,2 usebackq delims=|" %%A in (
    `powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\video\*' -Recurse -Include *.jpg, *.mp4 | ForEach {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name FullName, LastWriteTime, Extension} | ForEach {$_.FullName+'|'+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss')+$_.Extension}}"`
) do (
    move "%%~A" "C:\video\%%~B"
)
```

Note: You can leave out `-Path`, but then the first argument must be the path.